# prerender blocking googlebot identifier

Tags: javascript, seo, prerender

I am using self hosted dockerized prerender to render my SPA. When I am rendering desktop view via desktop agents/crawlers, it works fine and I am getting proper static html for page but when I am rendering mobile view via googlebot smartphone agent then I am getting black html page which I am not getting for any other mobile bot agent (Chrome - ANdroind Mobile, ANdroind (4.0.2) Browser - Galaxy Nexus etc.). After investigation I found that googlebot identifier string **(compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)** in user-agent string is causing this issue.

Here is my server.js and package.json file respectively:

```
'use strict';

const prerender = require('prerender');
const redisMemory = require('prerender-redis-cache');

const server = prerender({
    chromeFlags: ['--no-sandbox', 
                  '--headless', 
          '--disable-gpu', 
                  '--remote-debugging-port=9222', 
                  '--hide-scrollbars',
                  '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
    forwardHeaders: true,
    followRedirects: true,
    chromeLocation: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
});

server.use(redisMemory);
server.use(prerender.blacklist());
server.use(prerender.httpHeaders());
server.use(prerender.removeScriptTags());

server.start();
```

```
{
  "name": "prerender-alpine",
  "version": "6.5.0",
  "description": "lightweight prerender container built on alpine linux",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prerender": "5.20.2",
    "prerender-redis-cache": "0.2.2"
  }
}
```

Can any one please let me know what could be the issue. Is self hosted prerender is blocking googlebot identifier traffic or agent on purpose?

I tried by removing googlebot identifier (test purpose) from user-agent string and it works like charm. I want my self hosted prerender to render mobile view and generate static html via google smartphone bot and want to understand how and why prerender is blocking google bot identifier.